# Explicit vs intrinsic locking degradation in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, benchmarking

I have two almost identical classes that find next fibonacci number. The difference is that one of them uses intrinsic locking and the other uses explicit locking. Instrinsic locking implementation is much more faster than the one with explicit locking and also faster than STM or lock free implementations.

```
Impl/Threads      | 1      | 2      | 4      | 8      | 16     |
---               | ---    | ---    | ---    | ---    | ---    |
IntrinsicLocking  | 4959   | 3132   | 3458   | 3059   | 3402   |
ExplicitLocking   | 4112   | 5348   | 6478   | 12895  | 13492  |
STM               | 5193   | 5210   | 4899   | 5259   | 6733   |
LockFree          | 4362   | 3601   | 3660   | 4732   | 4923   |
```

The table shows average time of single computation of next fibonacci number. Tested on java 8 and 7. Code is placed on github https://github.com/f0y/fibench/tree/master/src/main/java/fibonacci/mdl

Can someone explain why intrinsic locking implementation wins?

Comment: Hmmm ... Which Java version are you using? I ask because of the explanation in the second paragraph in this blog entry: http://mishrabagish.wordpress.com/2012/12/17/explicit-vs-intrinsic-locks-in-java-ensuring-thread-scheduling-fairness/

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose 1.8 and 1.7

Comment: You are benchmarking how good these tools work at degrading a multi-threaded environment to a single-threaded performance. That’s the opposite of the goal of SMP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That benchmark is wrong on so many levels, it does not make sense to discuss the results yet.

Here's the simple cut JMH benchmark:

```
package fibonacci.bench;

import fibonacci.mdl.ExplicitLocking;
import fibonacci.mdl.FibonacciGenerator;
import fibonacci.mdl.IntrinsicLocking;
import fibonacci.mdl.LockFree;
import fibonacci.mdl.STM;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.BenchmarkMode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.GenerateMicroBenchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Level;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Measurement;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Mode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Scope;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Setup;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.State;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Warmup;

import java.math.BigInteger;

/*
   Implementation notes:

   * This benchmark does not exhibit a steady state, which means
     we can not do timed runs. Instead, we have to time single
     invocations; therefore preset benchmark mode.

   * Each iteration should start from the pristine state,
     therefore we reinitialize in @Setup(Iteration).

   * Since we are interested in performance beyond the first
     invocation, we have to call several times and aggregate
     the time; this is why we have batchSize > 1. Note the
     performance might be different depending on given batch
     size.

   * Since we have to provide warmup, we do many iterations.

   * The performance is different run to run, because we are 
     measuring sometimes undeterministic thread allocations.
     JMH does it for us, hence multiple forks.

   * We don't want the profiles for difference FibonacciGenerator
     to mix up. JMH already takes care of that for us by forking
     each test.
     */

@BenchmarkMode(Mode.SingleShotTime)
@Warmup(iterations = 100, batchSize = JmhBench.BATCH_SIZE)
@Measurement(iterations = 100, batchSize = JmhBench.BATCH_SIZE)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class JmhBench {

    public static final int BATCH_SIZE = 50000;

    private FibonacciGenerator explicitLock;
    private IntrinsicLocking intrinsicLock;
    private LockFree lockFree;
    private STM stm;

    @Setup(Level.Iteration)
    public void setup() {
        explicitLock = new ExplicitLocking();
        intrinsicLock = new IntrinsicLocking();
        lockFree = new LockFree();
        stm = new STM();
    }

    @GenerateMicroBenchmark
    public BigInteger stm() {
        return stm.next();
    }

    @GenerateMicroBenchmark
    public BigInteger explicitLock() {
        return explicitLock.next();
    }

    @GenerateMicroBenchmark
    public BigInteger intrinsicLock() {
        return intrinsicLock.next();
    }

    @GenerateMicroBenchmark
    public BigInteger lockFree() {
        return lockFree.next();
    }

}
```

On my Linux x86_64, JDK 8b129 and four threads it yeilds:

```
Benchmark                      Mode   Samples         Mean   Mean error    Units
f.b.JmhBench.explicitLock        ss       100     1010.921       31.117       ms
f.b.JmhBench.intrinsicLock       ss       100     1121.355       20.386       ms
f.b.JmhBench.lockFree            ss       100     1848.635       83.700       ms
f.b.JmhBench.stm                 ss       100     1893.477       52.665       ms
```